# How do i migrate sequelize in node js with 2 table referencing each other?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

How do I migrate sequelize with 2 table referencing each other? for example i have table roles & users, in table roles i have column created_by referencing to table users and in table users i have column roles_id referencing to roles, when i tried to run normally it says "relation roles does not exist"

Here is my code:

```
"use strict"

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // roles
    await queryInterface.createTable("roles", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      created_by: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "users",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      },
    })

    await queryInterface.addIndex("roles", {
      fields: ["name"],
    })

    // users
    await queryInterface.createTable("users", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      roles_id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "roles",
          key: "id",
          onDelete: "CASCADE",
          onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        },
      },
    })
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("roles")
    await queryInterface.dropTable("users")
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create mutually referential tables. The error `relation roles does not exist` is raised because the migration is attempting to create a foreign key reference to `roles`, but that table hasn't been created yet. The proper way to model the relation between `users` and `roles` is with an associative table. The following two table creation statements are functionally identical, choose either one (I don't use sequelize, so I'm presenting these as raw SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles(
  user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  role_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT users_roles_uk UNIQUE (user_id, role_id)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles(
  user_id bigint REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  role_id bigint REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT user_roles_uk PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id)
);
```

These statements create a table that defines a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `roles`. The constraint, `users_roles_uk`, prevents redundant occurrences. To convert to a one-to-one relationship (which is the model the original migration would have created), add unique constraints to `user_id` and `role_id`.

Comment: So its better to seperate the role_id column in the table user to a new table? is this the best practice for it? is this solution only good for this case or its better in general everytime it has 2 table referencing each other? how about if i have 3 table referencing ex: in table user i have id_role and id_user_type both table have created_by column, should i make table user_roles and user_type? btw thank youu

Comment: There are several ways to model associations between users and roles. For one-to-one and one-to-many associations, it is often sufficient to pick one of the tables to have a reference to the other without resorting to a third table. The best approach to modeling a particular association depends on how the association will be used.